# Chatbox/shoutbox/forum with the following features

Tags: chat, forum

I would like to set up a simple forum for a small number of users. The features I would like are the following, in order of priority:

- **logging on not compulsory for posting**.
- A single thread. All the messages are immediately visible - no need to "open" them.
- most recent message at the top by default.
- The ability to upload photos.

Chatango is the closest thing I've found so far, but its a little bit buggy and the maximum message size is rather restricted.

Comment: A weekend with PHP?

Comment: Or a weekend with Drupal as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [SMF](http://www.simplemachines.org)? you would need a [few modifications](http://custom.simplemachines.org) to add features but this should meet your requirements

Answer (score 1):

[phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/about/features/) fulfills all of your requirements. As of phpBB 3.0 [post sorting](http://www.phpbb.com/about/features/#forums) (your third requirement) is now supported as well. phpBB is free and open source, you can find [themes](http://www.phpbb3styles.net/) for it all over the internet.

You will need to do a bit of configuring in the admin panel for your requirements though. For the second requirement for example, you will need to create 1 forum with 1 topic inside it, and disallow users to create new topics. That way they can only reply on one thread.

Comment: I don't think you can force phpbb to have the messages "open", i.e. see the contents of the last few at a glance without having to click on the "subjects" one at a time.

Comment: You'd only have one thread though. You can configure your site to always redirect to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [PHPNuke](http://phpnuke.org/). It runs with PHPBB but allows for easier expansion and CMS.